# How to stop GADBannerView/MPAdView from getting ads?

Tags: ios, admob, mopub

I am using the 2 mediation for ads.

When IAP is purchased, I want to remove the ad banner.

Right now I use `removeFromSuperview` to remove the views. However, the ads are still being refreshed. How do I stop getting more ads?

Answer (score 0):

You also should probably release the GADBannerView as well as nil out your delegate. So if you do something like:

```
adBanner_.delegate = nil;
// Don't release if you're using ARC.
[adBanner_ release];
```

Of course this assumes you don't want to add the GADBannerView again at some point later in your application flow.

Comment: What if I am using ARC? Set adBanner_ = nil ?

Comment: Just don't call release if you're using ARC, nil'ing out the delegate should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its

```
[adBanner_ stopAutomaticallyRefreshingContents];
```

And I think its better to add the delegate nilling to (as RajPara suggested).